# How to validade a string used to query PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a function that constructs SQL queries using two parameters: the table name and the columns and values to be queried.

How can I validate/sanitize that these parameters (table, columns, values)?

I am currently importing a JSON file containing my tables and their respective columns and checking if the inputted values are in this JSON object, which seems hacky.

edit:

I am aware that node-postgres does sanitation. However, I want to be able to have optional parameters, such as updated_at in the example below, without having multiple string queries.

This is an example:

```
insert("users", {
  full_name: "John Smith",
  username: "jhsmith",
  email: "john.smith@email.com",
  created_at: "2019-08-18 21:26:43.237",
  updated_at: "2020-03-16 07:11:41.379"
});

Generates:

"INSERT INTO users
(full_name,username,email,created_at,updated_at)
VALUES ('John Smith','jhsmith', ...)"
```

Comment: You could run `explain` (**not** (!) `explain (analyze)`) and see if that generates any errors

Answer (score 0):

Well your Node/Postgres client library should handle the escaping / sanitization for you.

Are you using the `node-postgres` package? Then you can use the Parameterized Query flow:

https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#Parameterized%20query

Comment: I want to be able to have optional parameters, such as "updated_at" in the example. Since pg requires me to explicitly enumerate the paraments (using $1, $2, ...), I would have to use multiple strings depending if "updated_at" is null or not.